# Delete Selected Row in DGV C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

My Problem is:

1. I want to retrieve the data(row.Cells[4].Value) from the selected row then assign it in a variable.
2. After getting the data I want to delete the selected row using a button.

Here is my code:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (dataGridViewPOS.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
   {
       string qty = row.Cells[4].Value;
       dataGridViewPOS.Rows.Remove(dataGridViewPOS.SelectedRows[0]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Does the code work? If not, what is the problem? Help us understand whats wrong and what you're asking for.

Comment: row in (string qty = row.Cells[4].Value;) is underlined red

Comment: How about replace the `row` to `dataGridViewPOS.SelectedRows[0]`

Comment: why? the part where (string qty), will hold the data from the DGV selected row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you haven't defined the `row` variable.

Try:

```
if (dataGridViewPOS.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{
    var row = dataGridViewPOS.SelectedRows[0];
    string qty = row.Cells[4].Value;
    dataGridViewPOS.Rows.Remove(dataGridViewPOS.SelectedRows[0]);
}
```

**Edit**

This is just an answer-version of Alex's comment, I realized it after answering.

Comment: oh! thanks a lot I got it working now string qty = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[4].Value);

Comment: I'm a bit confused on @Alex answer what I did when he said to replace the row was  string qty = dataGridViewPOS.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value;

Comment: It is the same, I am simply declaring the row as a new variable before trying to get it's value.

Comment: oh I'm starting to get it now. I think what he means is to assign it to another variable. thanks anyway guys :)